# Html page not executing the java script

Tags: javascript

This is a simple hello world in java script which is ref. in html via separate js file. View Page Src of html shows this:

```
    <html>
    <head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="HelloWorld.js"></script>
    </head>
    </html>
```

HelloWorld.js :

```
<html>
<header>
  <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
     document.write("Hello World!");      
  </script>
</header>
</html>
```

But Hello World not displayed in browser when I double click the html file.

Comment: `HelloWorld.js` contains HTML. It needs to contain _only_ JavaScript.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

remove html, header, script tag in your js file

```
document.write("Hello World!");
```

Answer (score 1):

you js file contains HTML

```
<html>
<header>
  <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
     document.write("Hello World!");      
  </script>
</header>
</html>
```

Instead it should contain only js code like

```
document.write("Hello World!");
```

Comment: yes, then it works. Should not use <script> tag also.